# Caching result of setUp() using Python unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing

I currently have a unittest.TestCase that looks like..

```
class test_appletrailer(unittest.TestCase):
    def setup(self):
        self.all_trailers = Trailers(res = "720", verbose = True)

    def test_has_trailers(self):
        self.failUnless(len(self.all_trailers) > 1)

    # ..more tests..
```

This works fine, but the `Trailers()` call takes about 2 seconds to run.. Given that `setUp()` is called before each test is run, the tests now take almost 10 seconds to run (with only 3 test functions)

What is the correct way of caching the `self.all_trailers` variable between tests?

Removing the setUp function, and doing..

```
class test_appletrailer(unittest.TestCase):
    all_trailers = Trailers(res = "720", verbose = True)
```

..works, but then it claims "Ran 3 tests in 0.000s" which is incorrect.. The only other way I could think of is to have a cache_trailers global variable (which works correctly, but is rather horrible):

```
cache_trailers = None
class test_appletrailer(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        global cache_trailers
        if cache_trailers is None:
            cache_trailers = self.all_trailers = all_trailers = Trailers(res = "720", verbose = True)
        else:
            self.all_trailers = cache_trailers
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about using a class member that only gets initialized once?

```
class test_appletrailer(unittest.TestCase):

    all_trailers = None

    def setup(self):
        # Only initialize all_trailers once.
        if self.all_trailers is None:
            self.__class__.all_trailers = Trailers(res = "720", verbose = True)
```

Lookups that refer to `self.all_trailers` will go to the next step in the [MRO](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) -- `self.__class__.all_trailers`, which will be initialized.

Comment: How do I destroy `Trailers` when all the class tests are done (assuming I need to)?

Comment: @Tal If you're using Python >=2.7, you can create `all_trailers` in `setUpClass(cls)` and drop the reference to it in `tearDownClass(cls)` classmethods. See http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#setupclass-and-teardownclass

Comment: I'm not sure if something changed here since '08, but when I try this with the method named "setup" it doesn't seem to get called at all.  When I try with the method named "setUp" it runs, but the class member gets reset upon every iteration.  I'll update once I find a solution; I really wanted this one to work since it's so clean.

Answer (score 8):

An alternative to the proposed solution would be to use a more featured test runner like [Nose](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). With Nose, you can have module-level setup functions which will be run once for a test module. Since it is entirely compatible with unittest, you wouldn't have to change any code.

From the Nose manual:

> nose supports fixtures at the package,
>   module, class, and test case level, **so**
>   **expensive initialization can be done**
>   **as infrequently as possible**.

Fixtures are [described in detail here](https://pythontesting.net/framework/nose/nose-fixture-reference/). Of course, apart from fulfilling your use-case, I can also strongly recommend it as a general testing tool. None of my projects will leave home without it.

Comment: Good point. I have to add Nose to the list of things to know/try in 2009 :-)

Comment: It will be 15 minutes well spent. Just try running "nosetests" in the root of any Python project as a starter. It will run your current tests without you changing anything.

Comment: to be specific, this would be in a 'setup_class' method.   cf: http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/1.0.0/writing_tests.html#test-classes

Comment: The unittest module in Python 2.7 added class and module fixtures: http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#class-and-module-fixtures

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Python >= 2.7 you can use the [`setUpClass`](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass) method that is called only once for the whole unit test.

```
import unittest

from trailers import Trailers

class AppleTrailerTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        # only initialize all_trailers once
        cls.all_trailers = Trailers(res='720', verbose=True)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        # drop the reference explicitly to let the Trailers object be garbage
        # collected
        cls.all_trailers = None

    def test_one(self):
        # ...

    def test_two(self):
        # ...
```

Comment: In the example I added above, `tearDownClass(cls)` is not required, but I added it in response to Tal Weiss's comment to cdleary's answer.

Comment: How do you use `all_trailers` reference inside `test_one` and `test_two` methods ?

Comment: +1 for how to use ``all_trailers`` reference inside ``test_one`` etc.?

Comment: (you can use AppleTrailerTestCase.all_trailers to access the class variable inside of test_one and test_two )

Answer (score 1):

What is Trailers class doing?
If it holds some state, then you **have** to reset it each time unit test is being executed.

To solve your problem, I would use a mock object - just emulating the interface of Trailers, providing a faked set of data.

---

**Update**: as Trailers is only reading XML data, I would go for a solution like the one proposed by cdleary.

Comment: Trailers() retrieves and parsers an XML, it's read-only (so there's no saved state)

Comment: In that case, I would go for cdleary solution

Answer (score 0):

It's worth mentioning that during 2010 the testrunner used in the Zope/Plone world was released as a separate module, unsurprisingly called [zope.testrunner](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.testrunner). It supports caching setUps in the form of "Layers". Check it out.