# Unittest setUp/tearDown for several tests

Tags: python, unit-testing

Is there a function that is fired at the beginning/end of a scenario of tests? The functions setUp and tearDown are fired before/after every single test.

I typically would like to have this:

```
class TestSequenceFunctions(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUpScenario(self):
        start() #launched at the beginning, once

    def test_choice(self):
        element = random.choice(self.seq)
        self.assertTrue(element in self.seq)

    def test_sample(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            random.sample(self.seq, 20)
        for element in random.sample(self.seq, 5):
            self.assertTrue(element in self.seq)

    def tearDownScenario(self):
        end() #launched at the end, once
```

For now, these setUp and tearDown are unit tests and spread in all my scenarios (containing many tests), one is the first test, the other is the last test.

Comment: Which version?  The unittest module has been expanded to include a module_setup and module_teardown in Python 2.7.

Comment: 2.7 also introduced setUpClass() and tearDownClass() classmethods, which would let you have several classes in the same file with their own per-suite setup and teardown.

Comment: You can also [Disable logging for the entire module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67608284/3684790)

Answer (score 160, accepted):

As of 2.7 (per [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#setupclass-and-teardownclass)) you get `setUpClass` and `tearDownClass` which execute before and after the tests in a given class are run, respectively.  Alternatively, if you have a group of them in one file, you can use `setUpModule` and `tearDownModule` ([documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#setupmodule-and-teardownmodule)).

EDIT: Note that `setUpClass` and `tearDownClass` must be declared using `@classmethod`. Another answer to this question includes sample code.

Otherwise your best bet is probably going to be to create your own derived [TestSuite](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestSuite) and override `run()`.  All other calls would be handled by the parent, and run would call your setup and teardown code around a call up to the parent's `run` method.

Comment: All in all, I would really like to combine this answer with the one containing sample code; I hesitate only because it could be seen as depriving @CuriousLearner (and others who worked on that answer) of credit for creating that source code. Not sure if there's a standard stack overflow approach to these situations, apologies for not doing further research on this.

Answer (score 151):

I have the same scenario, for me setUpClass and tearDownClass methods works perfectly

```
import unittest

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls._connection = createExpensiveConnectionObject()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls._connection.destroy()
```

Comment: This should be updated to be the accepted answer because it shows a correct example and these functions HAVE to be classmethods in order to work, which is not mentioned in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 24):

Here is an example: 3 test methods access a shared resource, which is created once, not per test.

```py
import unittest
import random

class TestSimulateLogistics(unittest.TestCase):

    shared_resource = None

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.shared_resource = random.randint(1, 100)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.shared_resource = None

    def test_1(self):
        print('test 1:', self.shared_resource)

    def test_2(self):
        print('test 2:', self.shared_resource)

    def test_3(self):
        print('test 3:', self.shared_resource)
```

Comment: Yes. Its good. setUpClass executing only one for all three test cases.

Answer (score 1):

For python 2.5, and when working with pydev, it's a bit hard. It appears that pydev doesn't use the test suite, but finds all individual test cases and runs them all separately.

My solution for this was using a class variable like this:

```
class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    runCount = 0

    def setUpClass(self):
        pass # overridden in actual testcases

    def run(self, result=None):
        if type(self).runCount == 0:
            self.setUpClass()

        super(TestCase, self).run(result)
        type(self).runCount += 1
```

With this trick, when you inherit from this `TestCase` (instead of from the original `unittest.TestCase`), you'll also inherit the `runCount` of 0. Then in the run method, the `runCount` of the child testcase is checked and incremented. This leaves the `runCount` variable for this class at 0.

This means the `setUpClass` will only be ran once per class and not once per instance.

I don't have a `tearDownClass` method yet, but I guess something could be made with using that counter.

Answer (score 0):

```
import unittest

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.shared_data = "dddd"

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.shared_data.destroy()

    def test_one(self):
        print("Test one")
    
    def test_two(self):
        print("Test 2")
```

For more visit [Python
unit test document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass)