# Run setUp only once for a set of automated tests

Tags: python, unit-testing

My Python version is 2.6.

I would like to execute the test setUp method only once since I do things there which are needed for all tests.

My idea was to create a boolean variable which will be set to 'true' after the first execution and then disable more than one call to the setup method.

```
class mySelTest(unittest.TestCase):
    setup_done = False

    def setUp(self):
        print str(self.setup_done)
            
        if self.setup_done:
            return
        self.setup_done = True
        print str(self.setup_done)
```

The output:

```
False

True

--- Test 1 ---

False

True

--- Test 2 ---
```

why is this not working? Did I miss anything?

Comment: Unittest creates separate instances for each test

Comment: Don't do this. Implement some other mechanism. But don't try to change the meaning of `setUp`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unittest setUp/tearDown for several tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389639/unittest-setup-teardown-for-several-tests)

Answer (score 134):

You can use [`setUpClass`](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass) to define methods that only run once per testsuite.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Since I'm using Python 2.6.6 setUpClass is not available.

Comment: @JohnM.: You can download the unittest2 backport package and get all the new stuff on your older python-dist.

Comment: The question deals with Python 2, but since the answer is also valid for Python 3 I changed the URL since Python 2 is deprecated.

Answer (score 82):

[Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14306074/3357935) is correct, but here is an example to avoid some common mistakes I found, such as not calling `super()` in `setUpClass()` when `TestCase` is a subclass of `unittest.TestCase` (like in `django.test` or `falcon.testing`).

The documentation for [`setUpClass()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass) doesn't mention that you need to call `super()` in such cases. You will get an error if you don't, as seen in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29653129/update-to-django-1-8-attributeerror-django-test-testcase-has-no-attribute-cl).

```
class SomeTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user1 = UserProfile.objects.create_user(resource=SomeTest.the_resource)

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        """ get_some_resource() is slow, to avoid calling it for each test use setUpClass()
            and store the result as class variable
        """
        super(SomeTest, cls).setUpClass()
        cls.the_resource = get_some_resource()
```

Comment: Note this is relevant only when `TestCase` is a subclass of `unittest.TestCase`.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using Python 3 and found that the `cls` reference is also available in the `setup` method and so the following works:

```
class TestThing(unittest.TestCase):

  @classmethod
  def setUpClass(cls):
    cls.thing = Thing() # the `thing` is only instantiated once

  def setup(self):
    self.thing = TestThing.thing # ...but set on each test case instance

  def test_the_thing(self):
    self.assertTrue(self.thing is not None)
```

Comment: You cannot access cls within setUp, which is an instance method (the lower case setup() will not be called, because it is not a unittest setUp method, nor a method starting with 'test', which is probably why you did not get an error)
However, once you define the class variables in setUpClass, you can simply call self.thing in all the instance methods

Comment: Thanks, @khuang834. You're right. This was an oversight on my part.

Answer (score 3):

Place all code you want set up once outside the mySelTest.

```
setup_done = False

class mySelTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        print str(setup_done)

        if setup_done:
            return

        setup_done = True
        print str(setup_done)
```

Another possibility is having a Singleton class that you instantiate in `setUp()`, which will only run the `__new__` code once and return the object instance for the rest of the calls.
See: [Is there a simple, elegant way to define singletons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875/is-there-a-simple-elegant-way-to-define-singletons-in-python)

```
class Singleton(object):
    _instance = None
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(
                            cls, *args, **kwargs)
            # PUT YOUR SETUP ONCE CODE HERE!
            cls.setUpBool = True

        return cls._instance

class mySelTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # The first call initializes singleton, ever additional call returns the instantiated reference.
        print(Singleton().setUpBool)
```

Your way works too though.

Answer (score 3):

setup_done is a class variable, not an instance variable.

You are referencing it as an instance variable:

`self.setup_done`

But you need to reference it as a class variable:

`mySelTest.setup_done`

Here's the corrected code:

```
class mySelTest(unittest.TestCase):
    setup_done = False

    def setUp(self):
        print str(mySelTest.setup_done)

        if mySelTest.setup_done:
            return
        mySelTest.setup_done = True
        print str(mySelTest.setup_done)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you ended up here because of need to load some data for testing...
then as far as you are using Django 1.9+ please go for [setUpTestData](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase.setUpTestData):

```
class MyTests(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        # Set up data for the whole TestCase
        cls.foo = Foo.objects.create(bar="Test")

    def test1(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.foo.bar, 'Test')
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to dedupe the calls to setUp, just call it once.

For example:

```
class MyClass(object):
    ...

def _set_up():
    code to do one-time setup

_set_up()
```

This will call _set_up() when the module's first loaded. I've defined it to be a module-level function, but you could equally make it a class method of MyClass.

Answer (score 0):

for python >3 you can do it by defining `startTestRun`,`stopTestRun` of `unittest.TestResult class`. answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64892396/2679740

Answer (score 0):

An extension to the answer above, the following example demonstrates `setUp` vs `setUpClass`,

```
class TT(unittest.TestCase):
    A = None

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls) -> None:
        print("init A")
        cls.A = 1

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        print("this is set up")
        self.a = 1

    def test_a(self):
        print("test_a")
        print(self.a)
        pass

    def test_b(self):
        print("test_b")
        print(self.a)
        pass
```

Gives,

```
test_a init A
this is set up
test_a
1

test_b
this is set up
test_b
1
```

Here `setUpClass` can be used to set up some class variables and is only initiated once albeit with multiple tests. But `setUp` is initiated every time of each test.