# Update to Django 1.8 - AttributeError: django.test.TestCase has no attribute 'cls_atomics'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-1.8

I updated a Django 1.7 project to Django 1.8 and now get errors when I run the tests (that are subclasses of `django.test.TestCase`).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "env\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 962, in tearDownClass
cls._rollback_atomics(cls.cls_atomics)
  AttributeError: type object 'SomeTests' has no attribute 'cls_atomics'
```

If I debug through the test I can step through all lines without problems, but after the last line the exception is thrown.

This is an example test:

```
import django
import unittest
from django.test import TestCase
import logging
import sys
from builtins import classmethod, isinstance

class ATestTests(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        django.setup()
        logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr, level=logging.DEBUG)


    def setUp(self):
        self._app = Application(name="a")


    def testtest(self):

        self.assertIsNotNone(self._app)
```

My environment:

```
astroid==1.3.4
colorama==0.3.3
defusedxml==0.4.1
Django==1.8
django-extensions==1.5.2
django-filter==0.9.2
djangorestframework==3.0.5
djangorestframework-xml==1.0.1
eight==0.3.0
future==0.11.4
logilab-common==0.63.2
Markdown==2.5.2
pylint==1.4.1
python-dateutil==2.4.1
python-mimeparse==0.1.4
six==1.9.0
xmltodict==0.9.2
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you paste here a pip freeze?

Comment: @lapinkoira done that

Comment: mmm can I see the test implementation you run?

Comment: @lapinkoira I added more details

Comment: Do you still need this? "# Django 1.7 requires an explicit setup() when running tests in PTVS"

Comment: Is the full traceback crashing in the setup or the testtest()?

Comment: @lapinkoira the line `if django.VERSION[:2] >= (1, 7):` is not longer needed.

Comment: I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32700847/13521811)
answer from seddonym is the correct answer.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

For Django 1.8+, you should use `TestCase.setUpTestData` instead of `TestCase.setUpClass`.

```
class MyTests(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        # Set up data for the whole TestCase
        cls.foo = Foo.objects.create(bar="Test")

    def test1(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.foo.bar, 'Test')
```

The documentation is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase.setUpTestData).

Comment: Your comment resolves the error, but where in the documentation does it mention using `TestCase.setUpTestData` instead of `TestCase.setUpClass` for Django 1.8+?

Answer (score 154):

I believe the reason is that your `setUpClass(cls)` class method is not calling super. Because of that, `django.tests.TestCase.setUpClass` is not called and

```
cls.cls_atomics = cls._enter_atomics()
```

is not called, naturally causing `cls_atomics` to be undefined.

You should add `super(ATestTests, cls).setUpClass()` to your `setUpClass`.

Comment: This is it. If I add the call to the base class it works again (did I mention that it worked with django 1.7 ...). I Also do not need the call to `django.setup()`any more.

Comment: I thought i do not need `django.setup()` but i still need it in some cases, otherwise I get an exception that the model is not instantiated.

Comment: See @seddonym's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32700847/266375 - you should use setUpTestData not setUpClass .

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem where a `TestCase` used `setUpClass` but did not have a `tearDownClass` method.  My tests pass when I add an empty one:

```
@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    pass
```

I also do not call `django.setup`.

Comment: Following this answer could lead to problems with your teardown, where you have leftover objects and data that's otherwise not cleaned up. That can cause inconsistencies in your test suite, particularly if you run things in parallel.

Comment: @Jordan -- Yes, if you are creating any persistent objects, you should add some actual "cleanup" code to the teardown, I agree.

Comment: This avoids the the exception by stopping the call to the code causing the exception instead of actually fixing the problem.  Basically you won't get proper automatic ROLLBACKs after each test.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the complete code with the call to the base class (as suggested by [@J. C. Leitão](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29655301/254041)):

```
import django
import unittest
from django.test import TestCase
import logging
import sys
from builtins import classmethod

class ATestTests(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(ATestTests, cls).setUpClass()
        django.setup()
        logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr, level=logging.DEBUG)

    def setUp(self):
        self._app = Application(name="a")

    def testtest(self):

        self.assertIsNotNone(self._app)
```