# Selenium (python): How to execute methods in order

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, functional-testing

I have a Selenium Class with a  few methods:

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    cls.USER = 'user'
    cls.PASSWORD = 'password'
    cls.browser = Chrome()
    cls.browser.get('http...')

    def test_1(self):
    .....

    def test_2(self):
    .....

    def test3(self):
    .....
```

As I add more methods, the one that is called first when I execute the entire `MyTest` class changes. Sometimes method `test3` will get called first, but if I add another method, maybe `test2` will be called first. How can I make sure `test_1` is always called first?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execution order on python unittest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16364433/execution-order-on-python-unittest)

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) of unittest library :

> Note that the order in which the various test cases will be run is
>   determined by sorting the test function names with respect to the
>   built-in ordering for strings

So you just need to define method names in alphabetical order to run them in order. Just change method name `test3()` to `test_3()`.