# Python unitest - Use variables defined in module and class level setup functions, in tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, oop, nose, python-unittest

I am doing Python unit testing using *nosetests* to experiment with [Python class and module fixtures](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#class-and-module-fixtures), to have minimal setup across my tests.

The **problem** is I am not sure how to use any variables defined in the `setupUpModule` and the `setUpClass` functions in my tests (example: `test_1`).

This is what I am using to try out:

```
import unittest

def setUpModule():
    a = "Setup Module variable"
    print "Setup Module"

def tearDownModule():
    print "Closing Module"

class TrialTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        print a #<======
        b = "Setup Class variable"

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        print "Closing Setup Class"

    def test_1(self):
        print "in test 1"
        print a #<======
        print b #<======

    def test_2(self):
        print "in test 2"

    def test_3(self):
        print "in test 3"

    def test_4(self):
        print "in test 4"

    def test_5(self):
        print "in test 5"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

The error I get is:

```
Setup Module
ERROR
Closing Module

======================================================================
ERROR: test suite for <class 'one_setup.TrialTest'>
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 208, in run
    self.setUp()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 291, in setUp
    self.setupContext(ancestor)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose/suite.py", line 314, in setupContext
    try_run(context, names)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose/util.py", line 469, in try_run
    return func()
  File "/Users/patila14/Desktop/experimental short scripts/one_setup.py", line 13, in setUpClass
    print a
NameError: global name 'a' is not defined

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Of course, if I do `gloabl a` and `global b`, it will work. Is there a better way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unittest setUp/tearDown for several tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389639/unittest-setup-teardown-for-several-tests)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

For the string variable `a`, the only solution is `global a`. If you look at the [Python 2](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.17/Lib/unittest/suite.py#L178) and [Python 3](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.2/Lib/unittest/suite.py#L204) source code, `setupModule()` doesn't appear to do anything magical, so all the usual namespace rules apply.

If `a` were a mutable variable, like a list, you could define it at global scope and then append to it within setupModule.

**Variable `b`** is easier to work with because it is defined within a class. Try this:

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    cls.b = "Setup Class variable"

def test_1(self):
    print self.b
```