# Python Selenium: How to reuse a class from another class

Tags: python, selenium

I'm new to Python and selenium. I need to write a login module that I can reuse in my test cases. Here's my 2 files. I need help to call the login module so that the browser launches and user can login. Then the second module starts and test case begins (in the same browser). I have written 2 class in 2 separate files. My code is below:

mylogin.py file

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import unittest
class myLoginclass(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod   
    def test_TC_1_login_page(self):       
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get(http://www.gmail.com)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='name-group']/input").send_keys("HELLO")
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='password-group']/input").send_keys("WORLD")
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("loginButton").click()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(failfast=True, exit=False)
```

The myorder.py file:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import unittest
from mylogin import myLoginclass
class myorderclass(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod   
    def test_TC_2_orderProcess(self):       
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("".//*[@id='aoTkt']/div/div")).click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='presales']/input").click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("DISPATCH").click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("submitButton").click()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(failfast=True, exit=False)
```

Comment: Can you fix the formatting of your code?

Comment: fixed the indentation issues in my sample code

Comment: In `self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("".//*[@id='aoTkt']/div/div")).click()` you have "("...."))".().. which means you got one ")" bracket too much in your code. Typo?

Comment: yes, extra ) it's a typo . But the question is how to use the browser invoked from one class be used to continue with the next test case, which is written in another class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use class inheritance. Call the login function with either setUp() or setUpClass() depending on your use case.

```
from mylogin import myLoginclass

class myorderclass(myLoginclass):
    def setUp(self):
        self.test_TC_1_login_page()
```

[Unittest setUp/tearDown for several tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389639/unittest-setup-teardown-for-several-tests)

Comment: This solution partially works. The myorder class runs, which includes myloginclass followed by myorder class. But after this, myloginclass executes again, opening a new browser and login.