# Python unit tests run function after all test

Tags: python, unit-testing, ssh, python-unittest

I need to test smth on python via ssh. I don't want to make ssh connection for every test, because it is to long, I have written this:

```
class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    client = None
    def setUp(self):
        if not hasattr(self.__class__, 'client') or self.__class__.client is None:
            self.__class__.client = paramiko.SSHClient()
            self.__class__.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            self.__class__.client.connect(hostname=consts.get_host(), port=consts.get_port(), username=consts.get_user(),
                                password=consts.get_password())

    def test_a(self):
        pass

    def test_b(self):
        pass

    def test_c(self):
        pass

    def disconnect(self):
        self.__class__.client.close()
```

and my runner

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestSuite((
        unittest.makeSuite(TestCase),
    ))
    result = unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
    TestCase.disconnect()
    sys.exit(not result.wasSuccessful())
```

In this version I get error `TypeError: unbound method disconnect() must be called with TestCase instance as first argument (got nothing instead)`. So how i can call disconnect after all tests pass?
With best regards.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should use [setUpClass](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass) and [tearDownClass](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDownClass) instead, if you want to keep the same connection for all tests. You'll also need to make the `disconnect` method static, so it belongs to the class and not an instance of the class.

```
class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

     def setUpClass(cls):
         cls.connection = <your connection setup>

     @staticmethod
     def disconnect():
         ... disconnect TestCase.connection

     def tearDownClass(cls):
         cls.disconnect()
```

Comment: In `python 3` you need a `@classmethod` decorator on the class functions

Answer (score 9):

you can do it by defining `startTestRun`,`stopTestRun` of `unittest.TestResult` class. `setUpClass` and `tearDownClass` are running per test class(per test file) so if you have multiple files this methods will run for each one.

by adding following code to my `tests/__init__.py` i managed to achieve it. this code runs only once for all tests(regardless of number of test classes and test files).

```
def startTestRun(self):
    """
    https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult.startTestRun
    Called once before any tests are executed.

    :return:
    """
    DockerCompose().start()


setattr(unittest.TestResult, 'startTestRun', startTestRun)


def stopTestRun(self):
    """
    https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult.stopTestRun
    Called once after all tests are executed.

    :return:
    """
    DockerCompose().compose.stop()


setattr(unittest.TestResult, 'stopTestRun', stopTestRun)
```

Comment: So how exactly would you get the TestSuite to use your customized TestResult?

Comment: came across this answer, and just to clarify setattr is just in the class below the def stopTestRun

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a simple solution for the basic (beginner's) case:

```
def tmain():
    setup()
    unittest.main(verbosity=1, exit=False)
    clean()
```

The trick is "**exit=False**" which lets the function tmain run until the end.
setup() and clean() can be any functions to do what the name implies.