# Does Python's unittest have a global setUp for an entire TestSuite?

Tags: python, unit-testing, integration-testing, python-unittest

I'm a bit new to Python's `unittest` library and I'm currently looking at setting up my Flask server before running any of my integration tests.  I know that the unittest.TestCase class allows you to use `setUp()` before every test cases in the class.  I also know that the same class has another method called `setUpClass()` that runs only once for the entire class.

What I'm actually interested is trying to figure out how to do something similar like `setUpClass()`, but done on an entire unittest.TestSuite.  However, I'm having no luck at it.

Sure, I could set up the server for every TestCase, but I would like to avoid doing this.

There is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64892544/12783450) on a separate question that suggests that by overriding unittest.TestResult's `startTestRun()`, you could have a set up function that covers the entire test suite.  However, I've tried to passed in the custom TestResult object into unittest. TextTestRunner with no success.

So, how exactly can I do a set up for an entire test suite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not well documented, but I recently needed to do this as well.

The [docs mention that](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult.startTestRun) `TestResult.startTestRun` is "Called once before any tests are executed."

As you can see, in [the implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/63298930fb531ba2bb4f23bc3b915dbf1e17e9e1/Lib/unittest/result.py#L72), the method doesn't do anything.

I tried subclassing `TestResult` and all kinds of things. I couldn't make any of that work, so I ended up monkey patching the class.

In the `__init__.py` of my test package, I did the following:

```
import unittest


OLD_TEST_RUN = unittest.result.TestResult.startTestRun

def startTestRun(self):
    # whatever custom code you want to run exactly once before 
    # any of your tests runs goes here:
    ...

    # just in case future versions do something in this method
    # we'll call the existing method
    OLD_TEST_RUN(self)

unittest.result.TestResult.startTestRun = startTestRun
```

There is also a `stopTestRun` method if you need to run cleanup code after all tests have run.

Note that this does not make a separate version of `TestResult`. The existing one is used by the `unittest` module as usual. The only thing we've done is surgically graft on our custom implementation of `startTestRun`

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  So I've put this code inside of ```__init__.py```, but it never runs unless I use a TestSuite.  Why is this method very buggy/nonfunctional?

Comment: @JosephWoolf How are you running your unit tests?

Comment: So, the first approach that I used was to use a TestSuite and import the modified unittest fron ```__init__.py```.  While this did work, the issue was that the classes that held the tests ran twice, which isn't what I want.

Comment: The second approach was going into the file containing the test cases can importing the modified unittest from ```__init__.py```.  However, this approach didn't work at all

Comment: We're also using nose2 to run our tests

Comment: If you want to use the solution in this answer run your unit tests with the standard library. e.g.: `python -m unittest`. This is the reason running your tests with nose2 doesn't work: https://docs.nose2.io/en/latest/differences.html#internals

Comment: You might be able to leverage a nose2 feature if you need to use nose2 instead of `unittest` from the std lib. Perhaps this or something on this page will help: https://docs.nose2.io/en/latest/dev/hook_reference.html#startTestRun

Comment: @JosephWoolf to be clear: the only thing in the `__init__.py` should be what I have in the answer. No need to import your tests. Run your test suite via `python -m unittest`

Comment: @JosephWoolf it's also worth mentioning that if you are just testing your flask app, there isn't a need to run your flask server, just use the test client: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.test_client