# Python unittest startTestRun to execute setup only once before all tests

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have several test files in different directories.

```
\tests
    \subtestdir1
        -__init__.py
        -test1.py
    \subtestdir2
        -__init__.py
        -test2.py
    -__init__.py
    -test3.py
```

I need to do some setups only once before all tests in all test files.

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/66252981, the top-level `__init__.py` looks like this:

```
import unittest


OLD_TEST_RUN = unittest.result.TestResult.startTestRun


def startTestRun(self):
    print('once before all tests')
    OLD_TEST_RUN(self)


unittest.result.TestResult.startTestRun = startTestRun
```

I've tried this too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64892396/3337597

```
import unittest


def startTestRun(self):
    print('once before all tests')


setattr(unittest.TestResult, 'startTestRun', startTestRun)
```

In both cases, all tests ran successfully, but startTestRun doesn't execute. I couldn't figure out why. I appreciate any clarification.

(I use unittest.TestCase and run my tests by right click on the tests directory and clicking Run 'Python tests in test...')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in those 2 answers, the `startTestRun` method was not in any class. It should be like this:

```
import unittest

class TestResult(object):
    def startTestRun(self):
        print('once before all tests')


setattr(unittest.TestResult, 'startTestRun', TestResult.startTestRun)
```

If you need to tidy up after all tests, that's the same with `stopTestRun`:

```
import unittest

class TestResult(object):
    def stopTestRun(self):
        print('once after all tests')


setattr(unittest.TestResult, 'stopTestRun', TestResult.stopTestRun)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../src')
import vader
import unittest

class TestVader(unittest.TestCase):


    def setUp(self):
        self.testDbData = [DATA]

    def test_build_training_data(self):
        
        dataStruct = vader.build_data_struct(self.testDbData)
    
    def test_get_points(self):
        dataStruct = vader.build_data_struct(self.testDbData)
```

this is what i did for one of my project

Comment: The setUp method will run per each test and the setUpClass method will run per each test class. I need to run my setup only once before all tests of all test classes.

Comment: check this out :
https://stezz.blogspot.com/2011/04/calling-only-once-setup-in-unittest-in.html